# Email-To-Case - how to find if it's enabled

Tags: email2case

I am trying to find if the user has enabled `Email-to-Case`, is there a way to find using REST or APEX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Metadata API, you can get [CaseSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_casesettings.htm).

If On-Demand Service is enabled you can use the following.

You can query [EmailServicesFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailservicesfunction.htm) object to see if there is an entry for EmailToCase. If there is then it is enabled.

`SELECT Id, FunctionName from EmailServicesFunction where FunctionName = 'EmailToCase'`

You can also query [EmailServicesAddress](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_emailservicesaddress.htm) to see the email addresses associated with EmailToCase.

Comment: I don't find any entry in the `EmailServicesFunction` and `EmailToCase` enabled

Comment: Did you also enable On-Demand Service? I just tested in a Scratch org and the query results in a record for me.

Comment: No `On-Demand Service` is not enabled, can we check to see `email-to-case` without enabling `On-Demand Service` ?

Comment: It is available in the metadata API as well, it looks like. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_casesettings.htm